# How do I use the FindFit function to predict the function value for year 2050?

Tags: plotting

I was told by my teacher to use the FindFit function to predict the value of the year 2050 based on the following graph.

[image]

Here is the code:

`Show[%6, AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Year], HoldForm[IPL]},  PlotLabel -> None, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]`

And the data:

```
data = {{1985, 1.133431849`}, {1986, 1.160159779`}, {1987, 1.258499165`}, {1988, 1.621471213`}, {1989, 1.680828727`}, {1990, 1.915023226`}, {1991, 1.970753299`}, {1992, 1.995476342`}, {1993, 2.020698418`}, {1994, 2.244136414`}, {1995, 2.777442634`}, {1996, 3.118522316`}, {1997, 3.166145998`}, {1998, 3.300383074`}, {1999, 3.532421651`}, {2000, 3.669578913`}, {2001, 3.678014488`}, {2002, 3.81038489`}, {2003, 3.848093344`}, {2004, 3.897725791`}, {2005, 3.938631601`}, {2006, 4.15070104`}, {2007, 4.574372235`}, {2008, 4.590387261`}, {2009, 4.736301813`}, {2010, 4.915243763`}, {2011, 5.256494214`}, {2012, 5.272068892`}, {2013, 5.277945345`}, {2014, 5.7184}, {2015, 6.364346346`}, {2016, 6.389994038`}, {2017, 6.460901568`}, {2018, 6.577481081`}, {2019, 6.715864121`}, {2020, 6.938521183`}, {2021, 7.250230421`}, {2022, 7.328550817`}, {2023, 7.549019551`}, {2024, 7.779948309`}, {2025, 7.821071043`}, {2026, 8.174810316`}, {2027, 8.436307426`}, {2028, 8.892949455`}, {2029, 9.164109641`}, {2030, 9.532311582`}, {2031, 9.613334263`}, {2032, 9.958851422`}}
```

`ListPlot[data]`

They wrote:
“Fit appropriate models (exponential model, linear model, etc) to the data below so you can predict the world's future data. Use the FindFit function to find suitable coefficients for the models. Tip: Shift the time scale by t-> t-1990 to make it easier to find the parameters in FindFit for non-linear fits. "

Comment: Any appropriate analysis requires that error bands be produced (which will get wider the farther away from the data).  Also, note that the error bands for any model are constructed with the assumption that the model is the correct model for the time of extrapolation.  That ignores any "world events" especially with the extreme extrapolation you are proposing.  Because you apparently don't know what model to consider, that tells me the subject matter is not playing a role in the choice.  That seems  not to be a good thing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer depends on the choice of the fitting function (unless there is a preferable outcome that is pre-determined). One of the answers has already demonstrated two possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{1985, 1.133431849`}, {1986, 1.160159779`}, {1987, 
    1.258499165`}, {1988, 1.621471213`}, {1989, 1.680828727`}, {1990, 
    1.915023226`}, {1991, 1.970753299`}, {1992, 1.995476342`}, {1993, 
    2.020698418`}, {1994, 2.244136414`}, {1995, 2.777442634`}, {1996, 
    3.118522316`}, {1997, 3.166145998`}, {1998, 3.300383074`}, {1999, 
    3.532421651`}, {2000, 3.669578913`}, {2001, 3.678014488`}, {2002, 
    3.81038489`}, {2003, 3.848093344`}, {2004, 3.897725791`}, {2005, 
    3.938631601`}, {2006, 4.15070104`}, {2007, 4.574372235`}, {2008, 
    4.590387261`}, {2009, 4.736301813`}, {2010, 4.915243763`}, {2011, 
    5.256494214`}, {2012, 5.272068892`}, {2013, 5.277945345`}, {2014, 
    5.7184}, {2015, 6.364346346`}, {2016, 6.389994038`}, {2017, 
    6.460901568`}, {2018, 6.577481081`}, {2019, 6.715864121`}, {2020, 
    6.938521183`}, {2021, 7.250230421`}, {2022, 7.328550817`}, {2023, 
    7.549019551`}, {2024, 7.779948309`}, {2025, 7.821071043`}, {2026, 
    8.174810316`}, {2027, 8.436307426`}, {2028, 8.892949455`}, {2029, 
    9.164109641`}, {2030, 9.532311582`}, {2031, 9.613334263`}, {2032, 
    9.958851422`}};

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]

(* {1985, 2032} *)
```

For linear model

```
f1[x_] = a*x + b /.
  FindFit[data, a*x + b, {a, b}, x]

(* -358.805 + 0.181145 x *)
```

For quadratic model

```
f2[x_] = a*x^2 + b*x + c /.
  FindFit[data, a*x^2 + b*x + c, {a, b, c}, x]

(* 4737.83 - 4.89416 x + 0.00126346 x^2 *)

Show[
 Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, xmin, xmax},
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.8, .3}]],
 Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, xmax, 2050},
  PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Dotted}],
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[3], Red}],
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Year], HoldForm[IPL]},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Extrapolating to year 2050

```
{f1[2050], f2[2050]}

(* {12.5421, 14.4756} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
NonlinearModelFit[data,  a Exp[b (x - 1990)], {a, b }, x]
```